# how to get a sting using a array in php programming language

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have that array - `Array ( [0] => Rinku yadav [1] => r b name [2] => Rinku yadav )`

I want a sting in the form: - `[ "Rinku yadav", "r b name", "Rinku yadav" ]`

I am getting that array from a database but after getting I want it in the form `[ "Rinku yadav", "r b name", "Rinku yadav" ]`

Comment: use implode function.learn from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp).

Answer (score 3):

It's called [implode](http://php.net/implode)

```
$array = array('a','b','c');
$string = implode(", ", $array);
echo $string; // Result: [a, b, c]
```

As you can see, only 'glue' between the items, not after the last item.
For your exact question:

```
$string = ' [" ';
$string.= implode(' ", " ', $array); // Each item will be glued with -> [ ", " ]
$string.= ' "] ';
```

I've added a few spaces/newlines extra to improve redability

---

It's counterpart is [explode](http://php.net/explode)

```
$array = explode(", ", 'a, b, c');
```

Comment: I know implode and explode but by using that i am getting - Rinku yadav r b name Rinku yadav. But i want to echo [ "Rinku yadav", "r b name", "Rinku yadav" ]. So please help me.

Comment: just use the glue. Ill add an example

Comment: Actually tested answer is - $string = ' ["';
 $string.= implode('","', $array);
 $string.= '"] ';
 echo $string;

Comment: In your answer, i am getting a space in string OKay

Comment: Yes, to make it more readable. See the provided url for more information on how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use implode like this

```
$array = array('Rinku yadav','r b name','Rinku yadav');
$string = '['. implode(',', $array) .']';
echo $string;
```

Answer (score -1):

use this.

```
 $array=Array ( " Rinku yadav" ," r b name"," Rinku yadav ");
 $string = implode(", ", $array);
 echo "[".$string."]";
```

Comment: You do not have to provide the keys if you want to use a numbered index (like your example), it will do that automatically. This only decreases readability.

Comment: Also, im not really sure wether you're even allowed to use the brackets as key-indication. `array(0=>'a', 1=>'b')` will suffice

Comment: I just gave you two comments on that... An thats even without taken the fact that the answer was allready given and your reply was no addon whatsoever :)